# Add 30 seconds to time in yyyyMMddHHmmss format in java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

How to add 30 seconds to the datetime in the format `yyyyMMddHHmmss` in java

SO far I have done this

```
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        Date d;
        d = df.parse(requestDate);
        System.out.println(" date d "+d);
        Long time = d.getTime();
        time +=30;
        Date d2 = new Date(time);
        System.out.println(" date d2 "+d2);
```

And the output I am getting is not correct and both are same time . The output I am getting is

```
 date d Wed Apr 30 19:32:47 IST 2014
 date d2 Wed Apr 30 19:32:47 IST 2014
```

Comment: `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated and the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. I suggest you don’t use them and use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for your task instead.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "20180123123456" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( “uuuuMMddHHmmss” ) 
).plusSeconds( 5 )
```

## java.time

Use modern *java.time* classes rather than terrible old legacy classes.

Parse as a `LocalDateTime` as your input apparently lacks any indicator of offset or time zone.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( “uuuuMMddHHmmss” ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( “20180123123456” , f ) ;
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( 30 ) ;  // Represent a span of time unattached to the timeline. 
LocalDateTime later = ldt.plus( d ) ;
String output = later.format( f ) ;  // Generate a String representing the value of this object.
```

Tip: Use ISO 8601 standard formats instead.

Search Stack Overflow for more info. This has been covered many times already.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct idea, but made a small mistake. `getTime` gives the time in milliseconds, not seconds. So you need to add 30000.

Comment: You’re being very friendly. Using the long outdated `Date` and the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and hand-doing the calculation rather than relying on a standard class for the math — it may qualify as *one* correct idea depending on interpretation, certainly not *the* correct idea as in the only correct idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need add 30000 millisecond(30 sec)where 1000 Millisecond means 1 Second

```
 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    Date d;
    d = df.parse(requestDate);
    System.out.println(" date d "+d);
    Long time = d.getTime();
    time +=30000;//Here Change
    Date d2 = new Date(time);
    System.out.println(" date d2 "+d2);
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the Date.getTime() doc: Returns the number of milliseconds...

```
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
    Date d;
    d = df.parse(requestDate);
    System.out.println(" date d "+d);
    Long time = d.getTime();
    time +=30000; //<---milliseconds
    Date d2 = new Date(time);
    System.out.println(" date d2 "+d2);
```